# Reading an excel file : connection error from c#?

Tags: c#, excel, string, connection

My program needs to read some data in an Excel file.

**My configuration :**

Windows 10 x64 / Visual Studio 2019 / Office 2019 x64

And I've some trouble with this code :

```
string connectionString1 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=" + filePath22 + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
```

The connection string seems to be incorrect seen that I receive an error message :

*"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."*

I've already tried to install the "Microsoft Access database engine 2010 x64" and the "Microsoft Access database engine 2016 x64" but the problem continues...

Thanks for your help !  ;)

Comment: Found this forum post that suggests installing the Microsoft 2013 runtime. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/the-microsoftaceoledb150-provider-is-not/6430a47d-263c-43af-aabc-f134da4b830e 
Runtime link
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358

Comment: Yeah !!! It's working ! Thank you so much for your support !

Comment: No worries, I'll put it as an answer for anyone with the same issue if you don't mind approving it

Comment: I approve ! I approve !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this forum post that suggests installing the Microsoft access 2013 runtime.

Forum link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/the-microsoftaceoledb150-provider-is-not/6430a47d-263c-43af-aabc-f134da4b830e

Runtime link: https://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358